# df.rename wont rename a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to rename a column in a Data frame. I used the same line to rename the column "frames"

I want to rename a column from a "0" to "Grad"

```
result = pd.concat([table2, tableg3], axis=1)
result.rename(columns = {"0" : "Grad"}, inplace = True)
result
```

This outputs

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `{0 : "Grad"}`? What is the output of `result.columns`?

Comment: That worked. Don't know why though I thought 0 (not "0") referred to the y column?

Comment: Both are possible, it depends on what you did before. Anyway, problem solved, next time check `df.columns` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
"0" - string
0 - var
```

You havce to use    `{0 : "Grad"}`

```
result.rename(columns = {0 : "Grad"}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried {0 : "Grad"}? What is the output of result.columns?

Comment: This is a copy of one of the commentaries to the question. Did you intend to submit this solution of your issue as an answer? Then it needs editing as an answer, what you tried and got in result, crediting its author preffered.

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow, didnt know how to

Comment: That's alright, here you can always find something to learn from, like [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265676/3868453) on your case exactly, or on [something in general](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)